# Angular Basic Load Order

Tags: angularjs

In a very basic Angular app we have

```
<head>...
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="maincontroller.js"></script>
```

App defines the app module, and controller then hangs off app as app.controller("MainController..")  If the order of the two scripts is reversed, the app will throw an error "app is not defined".

Is there a way around this load order dependency?  My fear is that as it becomes more complex, I will get script order dependencies.  And perhaps I might want to load my scripts async as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad to load modules async.

Answer (score 3):

See, for example, this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kqVqTHxl4tc6mIV5bDbQ

I've defined `SomeService` in an own file, `svc.js`. I've defined the module and the main controller in `app.js`. And even though the `MainController` depends on that service that "loads later", the dependency is figured out, and injected. All you should worry about is: put the module definition first.

---

Also: Don't store the application inside a global variable called `app`, instead, use `angular.module` with the name of the module to retrieve a reference to it:

`angular.module('SomeModuleName').controller(...)`

Any kind of global variables are generally not a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Look at using [Angular and Browserify](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/08/angularjs-browserify/) or [Angular and RequireJS](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs). Browserify and RequireJS are module loaders that let you keep 1 script reference in your index.html.

[Browserify](http://browserify.org/) is based on a build step that will bundle all your JS into 1 file.

[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) is an Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) loader, that can load your files asynchronously.